# Disable 2 buttons after click of a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a submit button on page `index.php` When i click this button another script `(call.php)` is called through ajax that holds some response. Now i want that time between the click of submit button and response displayed/received under a div through the call of ajax script the buttons option1 and option2 should get disabled. and when succesfully the result is dispalyed the 2 buttons should get enabled, however i am not able to do so. can anyone help me with it

3 buttons  and script code on index.php page is

```
<button class="rightbtn" type="button" id="submitamt" style="display:none; ">Submit</button>
<a href="#popup"><button class="botleftbtn" type="button" id="walkaway" style="display:none">Option1</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="botrightbtn" type="button">Option2</button></a>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("You need to login before negotiating! However you can purchase the product without negotiating");
}
var startClock;
var submitamt;
var walkaway;
var digits;

$(function() {
  startClock = $('#startClock').on('click', onStart);
  submitamt = $('#submitamt').on('click', onSubmit);
  walkaway = $('#walkaway').on('click', onWalkAway);
  digits = $('#count span');
  beforeStart();
});

var onStart = function(e) {
  startClock.fadeOut(function() {
    startTimer();
    submitamt.fadeIn(function() {
      submitamt.trigger('click'); // fire click event on submit
    });
    walkaway.fadeIn();
  });
};

var onSubmit = function(e) {
  var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
  var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'call.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      txt: txtbox,
      hidden: hiddenTxt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(returndata) {
    $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
    },
    error: function() { 
      console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
    }
  });
};

var onWalkAway = function(e) {
  //console.log('onWalkAway ...');
};

var counter;
var timer;
var startTimer = function() {
  counter = 120;
  timer = null;
  timer = setInterval(ticker, 1000);
};

var beforeStart = function() {
  digits.eq(0).text('2');
  digits.eq(2).text('0');
  digits.eq(3).text('0');
};

var ticker = function() {
  counter--;
  var t = (counter / 60) | 0; // it is round off
  digits.eq(0).text(t);
  t = ((counter % 60) / 10) | 0;
  digits.eq(2).text(t);
  t = (counter % 60) % 10;
  digits.eq(3).text(t);
  if (!counter) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    alert('Time out !');
    resetView();
  }
};

var resetView = function() {
  walkaway.fadeOut();
  submitamt.fadeOut(function() {
    beforeStart();
    startClock.fadeIn();
  });
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by disabling the buttons before you make the AJAX request, and then enabling them again in the `complete` handler of the request. Try this:

```
var onSubmit = function(e) {
    var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
    var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
    $('.botleftbtn, .botrightbtn').prop('disabled', true); // < disable the buttons

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'call.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            txt: txtbox,
            hidden: hiddenTxt
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(returndata) {
            $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
        },
        error: function() { 
            console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.botleftbtn, .botrightbtn').prop('disabled', false); // < enable the buttons
        }
    });
};
```

Note that its best to enable the buttons in the `complete` handler and not the `success` handler. This is because if there is an error the buttons will never be enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the buttons on click, and enable them on ajax success:

```
var onSubmit = function(e) {
  var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
  var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();

  //Disable buttons ---------------------- //
  //Give an id to the second button
  $('#walkaway, #the_other_button').prop('disabled', true);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'call.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      txt: txtbox,
      hidden: hiddenTxt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(returndata) {
      $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
      //Enable buttons ---------------------- //
      $('#walkaway, #the_other_button').prop('disabled', false);
    },
    error: function() { 
      console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onsubmit() code, get a var reference to the buttons you wish to deactivate

```
Var btn1 = document.getElementbyId("btn1");
```

But you would have to set an Id for the two buttons.

You can disable these in your submit code and then enable them when your timer is done.

```
Btn1.disabled = true;
```

When your timer is done, set it as false the same way.